# IN operator with NSPredicate and SBElementArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting-bridge

Does the IN operator work for filtering SBElementArrays?  I have been trying to use it but it always returns a NULL array.

My code (hexArray will typically have more elements):

```
SBElementArray *musicTracks = [libraryPlaylist fileTracks];
hexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"3802BF81BD1DAB10"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@",@"persistentID",hexArray];

NSLog(@"%@", [[musicTracks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] valueForKey:@"persistentID"]);
NSLog(@"%@", hexArray);
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
```

Output:

```
2013-05-26 12:59:29.907 test[1226:403] (null)
2013-05-26 12:59:29.907 test[1226:403] (3802BF81BD1DAB10)
2013-05-26 12:59:29.908 test[1226:403] ANY persistentID IN {"3802BF81BD1DAB10"}
```

I have tried setting the predicate to:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == %@",@"persistentID",hexArray];
```

Output:

```
2013-05-26 13:03:04.629 test[1258:403] (3802BF81BD1DAB10)
2013-05-26 13:03:04.630 test[1258:403] (3802BF81BD1DAB10)
2013-05-26 13:03:04.630 test[1258:403] ANY persistentID == {"3802BF81BD1DAB10"}
```

And this works fine.  But I would like the IN functionality.

Comment: Without having tried this, my guess is that the `SBObjects` in the `SBElementArray` are not key-value-coding compliant for the `persistentID` key.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing

```
persistentID IN ('abc', 'abc', 'abc', ...)
```

you can do

```
persistentID == 'abc' OR persistentID == 'abc' OR ...
```

It seems to work pretty fast.

---

```
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:persistentIDs.count];

for (NSNumber *persistentID in persistentIDs) {
    [subPredicates addObject:pred(@"persistentID == %@", persistentID.hexValue)];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
[tracks filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%ld", tracks.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CONTAINS[c]`

Ex:-

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ CONTAINS[c] %k",hexArray, @"persistentID"];
```

Comment: The `CONTAINS` operator is only for strings.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just looping through all the elements of `hexArray` and using an equality predicate on each pass.  Probably not the most efficient, but it works.

```
for (NSString *hexID in hexArray){
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"persistentID == %@",hexID];
        iTunesTrack *track = [[musicTracks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] objectAtIndex:0];
        [track duplicateTo:playlist];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate should be `%K IN %@` (without the `ANY`), if I understand your intention correctly (get all the tracks that have one of the IDs in the array).

For some reason, this doesn't work with `SBElementArray`, but you could simply convert it to a regular `NSArray` before applying the predicate (an `NSSet` should work too, and might be more efficient):

```
SBElementArray *musicTracks = [libraryPlaylist fileTracks];
NSArray *musicTracksArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:musicTracks];

NSArray *hexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"CE24B292556DB1BA", @"CE24B292556DB1F0", @"CE24B292556DB1C4", nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"persistentID", hexArray];
NSLog(@"%@", [[musicTracksArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] valueForKey:@"persistentID"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripting Bridge technically supports the IN operator, in that it will construct a properly-formed Apple event for it, but most applications don't understand it.  The best workaround is the chained OR tests as suggested by NSAddict.